# how to let google spider detect the url correctly for front end rendering single

Tags: seo, google

I am building a front end rendering SPA using react.

It seems that the spider from google is able to run the js script, perform the ajax requests, render the whole page and cache it which is nice.

However, it seems that google think everything in SPA is in the root path

The figure below shows google result of one of my blog article (http://www.largetimber.com/post/2)

Google think it comes from the root path which is not.

[image]

Here is my question: Is there any tricks that I could do to let the google find the correct URL?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tested your pages with Google Fetch? since this is how you determine what Google can read and see.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.It's really helpful. I check the google fetch and it can only capture my home page. But there is another question, the information I searched is actually not available in the home page, how did google catch it ?

Comment: Google will only capture what it sees in the Google Fetch Render.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. And that's why I am course why the content in the figure can be caught by google. Home page is the only page that will be parsed properly and the content is not in the home page...Is it possible that in most of the time the ajax request is timeout but it success few times and that's the reason why google still get these pages ?

Answer (score 1):

You can to implement server side rendering in order to let the search engines bots correctly index your website. See an [exemplary solution](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/server-side-rendering-your-react-app-in-three-simple-steps-7a82b95db82e) and more details about [JavaScript frameworks and Google](https://www.elephate.com/blog/javascript-seo-experiment/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I've tried the ssr using node before and I knew it works. However I am using dotnet core for this project and adding a node middleware is too complicated. Actually SEO is not targeted but I am just curous about whether it could be possible after seeing google's strong ability in parsing javascript and ajax. btw, your second link is very helpful

Comment: Yes, Google can render JavaScript, but still it is the best solution to have server side rendered version for best search performance/ranking - [source](https://www.distilled.net/resources/split-testing-javascript-for-seo/). If you use .Net Core then have a look [here](https://hackernoon.com/server-side-rendering-of-deep-links-with-react-and-net-core-882830ca663).